# boost::iostreams::counter doesn't seem to work

Tags: c++, boost, iostream

I'm playing around with boost::iostreams and the user guide talks about filter "counter". So I try it with this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/null.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/counter.hpp>
namespace io = boost::iostreams;
int main()
{
    io::counter cnt;
    io::filtering_ostream out(cnt | io::null_sink());
    out << "hello";
    std::cout << cnt.lines() << " " << cnt.characters() << std::endl;
}
```

It always gives

```
0 0
```

which doesn't seem to be what I am expecting.
A preliminary tracing with gdb suggests the counter object that is doing the counting has a different address with object 'cnt'. I suppose it is some kind of copying in pipeline? If that's the case, how can filter "counter" be of any use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/counter.html) you can use either:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/null.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/counter.hpp>
namespace io = boost::iostreams;
int main()
{
    io::counter cnt;
    io::filtering_ostream out(cnt | io::null_sink());
    out << "hello";
    std::cout << out.component<io::counter>(0)->lines() << " " << out.component<io::counter>(0)->characters() << std::endl;
}
```

or:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/null.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/counter.hpp>
#include <boost/ref.hpp>
namespace io = boost::iostreams;
int main()
{
    io::counter cnt;
    io::filtering_ostream out;
    out.push(boost::ref(cnt));
    out.push(io::null_sink());
    out << "hello";
    std::cout << cnt.lines() << " " << cnt.characters() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: If you want to use `boost::ref` directly in the pipeline (avoiding the `out.push...` you need to use the macro found in this [post in the mailing list](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/boost-iostreams-Pipelined-reference-wrappers-of-filters-device-td2600264.html). Just put `BOOST_IOSTREAMS_EXTENDED_PIPABLE(io::basic_counter,1)` outside of main.